# Generality of the inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

An inner product on a vector space $V$ ( over field $F$ ) is a function $V \times V \to F$, which associates to each pair of vectors $\bar{x},\bar{y}$ of $V$ a scalar quantity $\langle \bar{x},\bar{y}\rangle$, and satisfies the following properties :  $$\langle \bar{x},\bar{x} \rangle>0$$

$$\langle \bar{x},\bar{y}\rangle=\langle \bar{y}, \bar{x} \rangle$$

$$\langle a\bar{x}+b\bar{y},\bar{z}\rangle=a\langle \bar{x},\bar{z}\rangle+b\langle \bar{y},\bar{z}\rangle.$$

Consider the subspace of all continuous functions on $[a,b]$ ; $\Bbb{C}$. Now, suppose we had some statement involving inner products that we wish to prove for vectors $\bar{x}, \bar{y} \in \Bbb{C}.$ For example, Let's say I choose to use the following inner product : $$\langle \bar{x},\bar{y}\rangle=\int_a^bx(t)y(t) dt.$$

If the statement is true for **this** inner product, is it then also true for all other inner products on $\Bbb{C}$?

Generally when working with inner products, there is a degree of choice as to what type of inner product is convenient for that particular situation - but what impact can this choice have ( if any )?

Comment: Note $\langle \bar{x},\bar{x} \rangle>0$ is not the right axiom. To your question: If in the proof you only use the axioms of the inner products, then the answer is *yes*. If you use any specific property of your specific inner product, then the answer is a firm *no*.

Comment: Since there are inner product spaces which are not isomorphic to each other, the answer is negative. For instance, notice how the truth of the statement "There exist 3 mutually orthogonal unit vectors" depends on the choice of the inner product space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a statement true for one inner product is not necessarily true for another. For instance, you can use an innner product to define a length
$$
\| x \| = \langle x,x \rangle^\frac12
$$

Under the standard inner product on $\Bbb R$ (defined by $(x, y) \mapsto xy$), we have
$$
\| 2 \| = 2
$$
for instance. But under a different inner product, $(x, y) \mapsto 2xy)$, we have
$$
\| 2 \| = 4.
$$
Now that may seem pretty contrived, but it can be tough to sort out the contrived from the uncontrived.